# Xquery variable concat based on condition

Tags: xquery

I am trying to concat the value of an element based on certain condition, but unable to do so. What's wrong here?

For below given sample structure, I need to concat the value of CID based upon OutcomeCode code. Say if we have OutcomeCode as OC and PC, then we should display concatenated value of CId in a string variable.

```
 <v4:ValidateResponse xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v4="http://service.com/v4">
   <v4:Details>
      <v4:Detail>
         <v4:CId>001</v4:CId>
      </v4:Detail>
      <v4:OutcomeCode>FC</v4:OutcomeCode>
   </v4:Details>
     <v4:Details>
      <v4:Detail>
         <v4:CId>002</v4:CId>
      </v4:Detail>
      <v4:OutcomeCode>PC</v4:OutcomeCode>
   </v4:Details>
     <v4:Details>
      <v4:Detail>
         <v4:CId>003</v4:CId>
      </v4:Detail>
      <v4:OutcomeCode>OC</v4:OutcomeCode>
   </v4:Details>
</v4:ValidateResponse>
```

Here is my transformation

```
as xs:string 
    {
    for $Details in $ValidateResponse /*:Details
        let $OutcomeCode := data($Details/*:OutcomeCode)
        return
       if (($OutcomeCode ='OC') or ($OutcomeCode='PC')) 
       then
            contact('CID is-',data($Details/*:Detail/*:CId))
        else 
            fn:data('Technical_Check')
    };
```

I am unable to get concat values.

Expected result should be like: **CID is- 002,003**
as these 2 meet the OC and PC condition.

Comment: Please attach the expected result to your question.

Comment: @ChristianGrün - updated with expected result..

Comment: There are several confusing things in your query: 1. There is no "contact" function in XQuery; 2. Your expected result does not include "Technical_Check", although there is a FC condition in your input, 3. your query starts with "as xs:string {". Is this intentional? Please spend more time in creating your questions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify this for loop and combine the criteria into a single XPath to select the `CId` from `Details` that have `OutcomeCode` of "OC" or "PC".

Then, use `string-join()` in order to produce a comma separated value.

Then, use `concat()` to produce a string with the prefix and the CSV value:

```
concat('CID is- ',
 string-join(
   $ValidateResponse/*:Details[*:OutcomeCode =('OC','PC')]/*:Detail/*:CId, 
   ",") 
)
```